# Hatching Density

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, pattern

I want to hatch a certain area using tikz's pattern library.

Here is what I currently have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw{(0,1.5) -- ++(0, -3)};
    \fill[pattern = north east lines, pattern color = black] (-1,-1.5) rectangle (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

(The weird grey line is an artifact, it disappears when I zoom in).

This is how i want it to look like:

[image: (Ignore the additional lines)]

(Ignore the additional lines).

Does anybody know how i can change the spacing between the lines?

Thanks!